# How to add fields to user's account in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

Im looking for how to add a field to a user's document in mongodb when he runs a certain command. Right now, this is all I have

new this.mongoose.Schema({
User: String,
Bobux: Number,
Tix: Number,
})

I want to add a field called "game name" when the user runs a command called $creategame. How would I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let userSchema = new this.mongoose.Schema({
User: String, Bobux: Number, Tix: Number,
GameName: String,
});

let User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.findOneAndUpdate({ User: 'their username', }, { 'GameName': 'their game name' }).then(console.log);
```